# Keras : problem with gradients, custom layer won't work in a sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer, tf.keras

This is the error message I get with the code down below:
**ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0'].**
right after it goes through the whole layer's build(), in model.fit().

It prints the input and the scalar after going through build() and before raising the error, but the tensors are both empty:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)  
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float>
```

My goal was to write a (basic) custom layer and to insert it in a (basic) model. 
My custom layer works properly on its own but I can't get the model to fit.
The layer take a tensor and multiply it by a scalar. I want my model to give me input*(scalar I chose early on).

Thus far I've gotten plenty of Error Warning about the dtype of various tensors (I had int32 instead of float32) so I wrote plenty of casts, and I had a model more complex but I stripped it to the bones to debug (it didn't help much…).

I tried with and without a "build()", with and without using "to_categorical" on the labels, with vector inputs and scalar inputs, and other probably insignificant stuff.

Here is the code of the layer:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
import h5py
import numpy as np


class MyBasicLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self)
        self._set_dtype_policy('float32')
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(1,), initializer='zeros', trainable=True)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
        if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
            raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `MyBasicLayer` should be defined. Found `None`.')
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs)
        print(self.w)
        return tf.math.multiply(tf.dtypes.cast(inputs,dtype='float32'),self.w)
```

And here is the code of the model:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from my_basic_layer import MyBasicLayer
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras import activations



k = 2.

# load the dataset
inset = np.array([[i] for i in range(40)], dtype='float32')
outset = inset * k
#outset = to_categorical(outset, num_classes =256)

# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(MyBasicLayer(input_shape=(1,))) #input_shape=(4,)
#model.add(Activation(activations.softmax))

# compile the model
model.compile()

# fit the model
model.fit(inset, outset)
model.summary()
```

Maybe relevant for all I know:
I wanted to have a model.summary() before the compilation but I got
**This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.**
even after adding *el famoso* `input_shape` argument in the first layer.

Thank you

Comment: You cannot have integer weights, gradients are only defined for continuous variables.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thanks, I still have this once w is a float though: **ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0'].**

Comment: Do you know about this github thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511 ?

Comment: You're welcome. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: It explains (partially) why my code works when I add `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` as an argument in `model.compile()`! I was just going to edit my post when I saw your comment. I don't know how to close the question btw, what should I do?

Comment: You could either delete it or write an answer yourself. I advise to do the latter to preserve this information for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Sections, for the **benefit of the Community**.

The error, `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0'].` in the above case is because **No Loss Function was provided** when the `Model` is `Compiled`.

So, replacing

```
model.compile()
```

with

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

will fix the error.

For the sake of completeness, the Simple working example code which uses `Custom Layer` is shown below:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
import h5py
import numpy as np


class MyBasicLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self)
        self._set_dtype_policy('float32')
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(1,), initializer='zeros', trainable=True)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
        if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
            raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `MyBasicLayer` should be defined. Found `None`.')
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs)
        print(self.w)
        return tf.math.multiply(tf.dtypes.cast(inputs,dtype='float32'),self.w)

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras import activations



k = 2.

# load the dataset
inset = np.array([[i] for i in range(40)], dtype='float32')
outset = inset * k
#outset = to_categorical(outset, num_classes =256)

# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(MyBasicLayer(input_shape=(1,))) #input_shape=(4,)

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# fit the model
model.fit(inset, outset)
model.summary()
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
my_basic_layer_3 (MyBasicLay multiple                  1         
=================================================================
Total params: 1
Trainable params: 1
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!